# Undefined variable Issue Between Different PHP Version?

Tags: php, codeigniter, undefined

I am using XAMPP 1.7.2 (PHP 5.3) to devlope on winxp localhost.
There is a function works quite well. Comes from CodeIgniter Module.

```
function get_cal_eventTitle($year, $month){
        $this->db->where('eventYear =', $year);
        $this->db->where('eventMonth =', $month);
        $this->db->select('eventTitle');
            $query = $this->db->get('tb_event_calendar');

        $result = $query->result(); 

        foreach ($result as $row)
        {
            $withEmptyTitle = $row->eventTitle;         
            //echo $withEmptyTitle.'<br>';
            $noEmptyTitle = str_replace(" ","%20",$withEmptyTitle);
            $withUrlTitle = '<a href='.base_url().'index.php/calendar/singleEvent/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$noEmptyTitle.'/'.'>'.$withEmptyTitle.'</a>';         
            //echo $withUrlTitle.'<br>';
            $row->eventTitle = $withUrlTitle;          
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

When I upload my code to remote server(PHP 5.2.9).  It show error as this,

**withEmptyTitle undefined variable**

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: withUrlTitle

Filename: models/calendar_model.php

Line Number: 54 // $withEmptyTitle = $row->eventTitle;
```

But When I enable the comment for the line `echo $withEmptyTitle.'<br>';`. It works well on remote server.

Assuming `withEmptyTitle` echo to **Apr running event** here.

I don't know why? Could you give me some suggestion to fix this issue? Appreciated for your input.

Comment: Are you sure this code gives the error? What is the actual line?

Comment: Note that PHP 5.2 is officially out of support, so your remote server should be upgraded to 5.3 if possible. Even if you can't do that, it should *definitely* be upgraded to 5.2.17, which was the last security update for 5.2 - your current version 5.2.9 is badly out of date and probably insecure.

Comment: @Khez, Yes, I tested with both Chrome and IE 5.0 on my winxp

Comment: please, write whole error message here

Comment: @Nano I chuckled when I saw you tested with 2 browsers. Please update with entire error message and tell us which line in the file that resolves to.

Comment: @ALL, I updated the post with completed error.

Comment: @Nano: What if you set `withEmtpyTitle` to `""` at the start of the loop?

Comment: @Nano: tested on IE5?????????!!!!! Woah. Do you seriously have any users with IE5?

Comment: @Spudley, It should be IE6. I downgraded it from IE7 to IE6 days ago.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is probably not an *error*, but a *warning*.

PHP may be throwing the warning because you're using a variable that hasn't been initialised. It sounds likely that your local development PHP installation has warning messages supressed, whereas your live server has them enabled. (In fact, best practice would be to have it the other way round!)

In this case, it's possible that `$withEmptyTitle = $row->eventTitle;` is not initialising the `$withEmptyTitle` variable, if the `eventTitle` property is returning as unset. It would then fall following line and throw the warning when you try to use the variable in the `str_replace()` call.

You could avoid this warning by:

- Switching warning message off in the PHP.ini
- Doing `ini_set()` to switch it off during the program.
- using `isset($withEmptyTitle)` to check that the variable is set prior to actually using it.
- Ensuring that `$row` does actually contain an `eventTitle` property (in the context of your program, if it's missing, it may imply bad data or incorrect database table setup? In any case, you could change the SQL query to use `IFNULL()` or at least ensure the field is explicitly queried.

[EDIT]

I see you've edited the question. In particular, I note the following:

```
Line Number: 54 // $withEmptyTitle = $row->eventTitle;
```

I note the `//` .... does that imply that the line is commented out?? Have you somehow got a copy on the server which has that line commented? That would certainly explain the fact that you're getting warnings!